# How to split and concatenate two bytes

Tags: c++, arduino, bitwise-operators

I am playing around with an 8x8 led matrix and have managed to get various shapes and letters to display and scroll. Currently i am working on some code to scroll text using some 595 shift registers, I have managed to get each letter in a word to scroll onto and off the matrix however i am trying to figure out how to remove the whitespace in between the letters. The whitespace is coming from me shifting bits using << and >> to move the letter on and off the matrix to create the scrolling effect.

Is there some bit math i can do to split the bytes as they get shifted in and concatenate the next byte onto it? This is what i am thinking is the solution but don't know how to go about it.

Please excuse my programming horror  i am very much still learning and am open to constructive criticism.

```
// Entire for loop block first moves each letter in from the right then scrolls it out the left
for(int numOfLetters = 0; numOfLetters < 2; numOfLetters++){

// This for loop block scrolls the each letter in from the right to the middle of the matrix
 for(int z = 8; z > 0; z--){
  for(int speedOfScroll = 0; speedOfScroll < 5; speedOfScroll++){
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
    shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, LSBFIRST, row[i]); // Rows
    shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, LSBFIRST, column1[numOfLetters][i] >> z); // Columms
    digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
    delay(2);
  }    
}
 }

// This for loop block scrolls each letter from the middle of the matrix to the left
  for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++){
for(int speedOfScroll = 0; speedOfScroll < 5; speedOfScroll++){
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
      digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
      shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, LSBFIRST, row[i]); // Rows
      shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, LSBFIRST, column1[numOfLetters][i] << y); // Columms
      digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
      delay(2);
    }
  }
}
  }
}
```

Comment: What confuses me is why you right-shift first (`>> z`), but then continue by left-shifting (`<< y`). Aren't you always scrolling from right to left? Anyway, in general if you have two bytes `high` and `low` and you want to shift `n` bits from `low` to `high`, you can get the overflowing bits by shifting back: `char overflow = low >> (8-n)`. Now, when shifting `high` by n bits, `high` has n zeros at the beginning, where you can now insert the overflowing bits by ANDing: `char newHigh = (high << n) & overflow`. Hope this helps

Comment: I’m using an multidimensional array of 8 bytes in each dimension so in the first for loop I shift one byte from far right to the middle of the matrix then in the second for loop I shift it from the middle to the far left. I tried >> up to -8 in the for loop but it didn’t work that’s how I ended up at the solution I have.

Comment: But why is there a difference between going from right to middle and from middle to left. Why don't you just move your bytes from right to left directly?

Comment: I don't know how... I tried using for(int z = 8; z > -8; z -- ) but the scrolling effect stops in the middle of the matrix

Comment: That's because when z becomes negative, you're shifting by a negative value. And that is undefined behaviour in C++, meaning even though it's not disallowed, anything could happen and is therefore discouraged.